# Create custom BackKey to navigate through framents

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I got the next FragmentActivity. This FragmentActivity inflates a layout with a LinearLayout(a menu where some buttons are defined to call other fragments) and a FrameLayout (a black space where the other fragments are loaded depending the button I select).

```
public class MenuViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
....
```

I load the selected Fragment using onClickListener:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....

final OnClickListener fragment_1 = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        fragment_1 Fragment = new fragment_1();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
};
```

I do this for about 5 buttons. This menu also contains a custom back key. The functionality of this back button should be like:

```
[fragment_1][fragmen_2][fragment_3][fragment_4][fragment_5]
```

The app starts always showing fragment_1. I con go from fragment_1 to any of the other fragments. So I could go for example from [fragment_1] to [fragment_4]. When pressing the back key I should go back to [fragment_1].

To detail a little bit more the functionality, I could do: [fragment_1]->[fragment_2]->[fragment_3] and when pressing back, should go back to [fragment_1].

I've got a onClickListener for the back key, but I don't know how to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

also if you're unaware that's the default functionality for the actual android back button, so unless you've overrode it that will do the same thing.

Comment: How would you implement this with my code? I haven't back button, I'm developing on a PCB board, not tablet neither phone

Comment: well you would put that in the onClick for your back button, for your dev board it should have some interface for back buttons, however that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Yes it has some kind of selector for backkey, but I'm developing a launcher type interface that won't have fisical buttons, so I need this virtual back button to work with. Just adding this to my onClikListener, without adding nothing more would work?

Comment: yea, you might also have to call `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` to figure out if you're at the end but that's all you need, fragments were designed for this that's why it's so simple. If you want more details you're going to have to provide more of your source code.

Comment: Where do I have to call that function? Well, haven't got to much code to include, just the layout inflated at the start, and then other 5 onClickListeners same as the one posted, but calling to other fragments

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pop all fragments from your backstack, unless you reach the one you want. It is probably simplest to use FragmentManager's [popBackStack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack%28int,%20int%29):

> **public abstract void popBackStack (int id, int flags)**
>
> Pop all back stack states up to the one with the given identifier

Comment: Could you please give an example implementing this with my code? I'm a bit new with this a it takes little far for my knowledge